# Http cookie is not send back to server, even when credentials is set to true and SameSite is set to none. [Duplicate?]

Tags: express, cookies, jwt, svelte

I am creating an express app. I want to use cookies to save a jwt token. However, I am running into an issue where the browser receives a cookie but then doesn't send it back.
My stack is: express.js and svelte.js
My guess is, is that it is a cors error. I have tried:
setting allow-controll-access-credentials : true
SameSite : 'none'

On the client headers:
credentials : 'include'
mode : 'cors'

And for testing purposes, I have set 'httpOnly' to false, so I can check whether I actually received a cooke.

code for sending the cookie:

```
router.post("/cookie", (req, res) => {
    if(req.body == null || req.body.emailAddress == null || req.body.password == null){
        res.status(StatusCodes.BAD_REQUEST).json(ReasonPhrases.BAD_REQUEST)
    } else {
        const email = req.body.emailAddress
        const password = req.body.password

        const user = findSingleUserByEmail(email)

        if (user && user.password) {
            const result = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)
            if(result) {
                const accessToken = jwt.sign({ email: user.emailAddress,  role: user.role, username: user.username }, user.secret)
                res.status(StatusCodes.CREATED)
                    .cookie('access_token', accessToken, cookieOptions)
                    .status(StatusCodes.CREATED)
                    .json(ReasonPhrases.CREATED)
            }else {
                res.status(StatusCodes.FORBIDDEN).json(ReasonPhrases.FORBIDDEN)
            }
        }else {
            res.status(StatusCodes.FORBIDDEN).json(ReasonPhrases.FORBIDDEN)
        }
    }
})
```

fetch client

```
            fetch(URL + PORT + '/auth/cookie', setRequest('POST', null, body))
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
                $tokenStore = true
            })
```

network tab output:
Set-Cookie: access_token=(cookie contents); Path=/; Expires=Wed, 28 Sep 2022 02:50:57 GMT

Finally, I was able to get it to work with Postman.

Comment: `SameSite=None` also requires `Secure`, otherwise some browsers won't set the cookie.

Comment: @jub0bs I use cors, does that mean I can just add secure : true, to my cors options?

Comment: `Secure` is a cookie attribute; it's got nothing to do with CORS.

Comment: @jub0bs, so in the example code above I have cookie options. In cookieOptions I have set SameSite to none and Secure to true. I read that, Secure is only available for https connections. Is that true?

Comment: Yes. In modern browsers at least, an insecure origin (e.g. on `http://example.com`, as opposed to `https://example.com`) cannot set a `Secure` cookie.